# How to force cleanup of BitmapImage in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am performing a set of operations against some images within a Silverlight OOB application however I am experiencing OutOfMemoryExceptions when performing these operations against multiple larger images.  The images themselves are around 15mb JPEG files, which individually use up around 100mb memory when loaded into a BitmapImage.

I am processing these images one by one, however the BitmapImage itself isn't being cleaned up between images.  When processing 10 images the memory usage (as shown in Task Manager) grows to over a gig in size before collapsing back to 100mb once the process is complete.

I've distilled the issue down to an in browser test application which simply loads the image data into a BitmapImage object, and consists of the following code:

```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] imageData = LoadImageData();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
            {
                bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);
            }

            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    private byte[] LoadImageData()
    {
        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ImageLoadingMemoryIssue.largeimage.jpg"))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            return buffer;
        }
    }
```

How do I force the `BitmapImage` to be cleaned up between each iteration within the loop to prevent memory issues when processing multiple files?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried keeping a global variable and setting its source instead ?

Comment: This makes no difference, the memory usage doesn't get cleaned up.  I've also tried setting the source to a small image to force it clean up - there's something that isn't getting cleaned up here correctly.  It does go eventually once you drop out of the loop, so it isn't a memory leak in the traditional sense.

Comment: If this is the case then, have you tried to put the content of the for loop in a method ? I don't know much about Silverlight but can you profile your application with something like http://memprofiler.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by waiting for the ImageOpened/Failed events before continuing on and loading and processing the next image.  For some reason this allows the memory to be cleared up at that point rather than waiting for all images to be loaded.

```
    private static async Task<BitmapImage> LoadBitmapImageAsync(byte[] imageData)
    {
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

        TaskCompletionSource<object> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> openedHandler = (s2, e2) => taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(null);
        EventHandler<ExceptionRoutedEventArgs> failedHandler = (s2, e2) => taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(null);

        bi.ImageOpened += openedHandler;
        bi.ImageFailed += failedHandler;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            bi.SetSource(memoryStream);
        }

        await taskCompletionSource.Task;

        bi.ImageOpened -= openedHandler;
        bi.ImageFailed -= failedHandler;
        return bi;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);
        }
        // release reference underlying byte array
        // see: http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/04/memory_leak_with_bitmapimage_and_memorystream.html
        bitmapImage.SetSource(null);
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Comment: That was one of the earlier things I tried, apart from the `SetSource(null)` throwing an Exception, it doesn't cause the memory usage to be released, although I've now found a way of causing it to happen

Comment: I also tried the Wrapped stream approach as mentioned in the linked article.  I think the article is more around WPF as I don't see the memory issue as described.